# 24V to 3.3V Level Shifter

Tags: integrated-circuit, voltage-divider, level-shifting

this is my first post so please excuse me for incomplete or improper text.

I am developing an interface board to connect ‘Converter control unit’ to HIL system. For this purpose I need to level shift 25 channels from 24V to 3.3V . The problem is that I am not allowed to use optocouplers and implementing 25 voltage dividers is a troublesome task. Using a multiplexer is also out of option because we are using all the channels since its real-time simulation. So I was looking for 8-channel level shifting IC but couldn’t find any. Please suggest me the possible alternatives or other methods to get this working.

Thank you.

Comment: The 24V requirement will rule out most (if not all) of the levelshifter ICs. So you will have to lower the voltage anyway before you could use an IC. Then it is simpler to just use resistor voltage dividers or a resistor and a 3.3 V zener diode per signal.

Comment: If you are developing the interface (as you say) then tell whoever is restricting your usage of stuff to stick their ideas where the sun don't shine. Use voltage dividers - there are IC like resistor packs that can kind of do what you think you wanted.

Comment: Implementing voltage dividers is the *easiest* of all the alternative ways to do it. Use 4 packs, or 8 packs of resistors. You can get 16 DIL 8 packs of individual resistors for the series arms. You can get 16 DIL 15 packs of resistors with a commoned terminal for the bottom arms.

Comment: are the signals are digital or analog ?

Comment: Thank you all for your valuable comments, i guess now i can convinence my supervisor. @ElectronS, these are digital signals.

Comment: then it is easy use a simple resistor and zener , what out for zener capacitance if signals are really high speed

Comment: you could also use a optocoupler array , and make the grounds common since you donot need the isolation

Comment: @ElectronS thanks for your suggestion, but i am not allowed to use optocouplers as i mentioned earlier. I guess i will go for voltage dividers with zener diodes, need to proceed only after discussing with my supervisor who is on vacation at the moment.